# Problem with call_user_func_array front end

Tags: hooks, errors

This is the error im currently getting, fixed the other minor ones but this one seems to be a compatibility issue. is there any way i can change a few lines of code to fix this issue, Any help would be great!

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'UKVD_uk_vehicle_plugin_script' not found or invalid function name in /home/compu280/public_html/winmillmotors.co.uk/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286

Domain - https://winmillmotors.co.uk

WP Hook file line 286 - 
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args

[image]

Comment: There's no compatibility issue. Or an issue with the specified file. This error occurs if your code uses `add_action()` or `add_filter()` with a function that doesn't exist. Either the `UKVD_uk_vehicle_plugin_script` function doesn't exist or you've spelt it wrong somewhere. You probably deleted or renamed the function without updating the `add_action()` or `add_filter()` call.

Comment: strange, i downloaded the plugin the same like i do all my plugins via the WordPress database 

https://wordpress.org/plugins/uk-vehicle-data-api/

added the api and everything the way it explained to, tried reinstalling everything man

Comment: I just had a quick look at the plugin, and it's just a bug in the plugin. They're doing what I said the problem was. This  is not a well written plugin, to say the least. If you want to fix the problem you can delete line 39 of uk_vehicle_plugin.php, but the issue will come back if you update the plugin and the author hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Thank you man it got rid of the error and now im getting a new one yay!!

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in //public_html/winmillmotors.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/uk-vehicle-data-api/uk_vehicle_options/UKVD_ValidateApiKey.php on line 6

Comment: It's probably another bug in the plugin. You should take your issues to the author. It's late here and I'm not going to go through it line by line, sorry.